# set value of object stored in variable to null

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I just discovered today that doing this:

```
a = { b: { c: 1, d: 2 }, d: {} }
sub = a.b
// sub is { c: 1, d: 2 }
```

`sub` is now actually the object stored in a, not a clone.

Now if I do this:

```
sub.c = "x"
// a is now: { b: { c: 'x', d: 2 }, d: {} } // nice
```

The same thing applies to arrays.

So I have this array:

```
arr = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {c: 3, d: 4}]
sub = arr[1]
```

I'd like to remove `sub` from array so that `arr` becomes: `[{a: 1, b: 2}]` but if I do `sub = null` I simply assign a new value to `sub`. Same thing for `delete`.

```
delete sub // will unset the sub variable, not the object that it references.
```

So the question is: how do I remove `{c: 3, d: 4}` from the array by using `sub`

Even though it works, I can't use `delete arr[1]` because I don't know the index. I'm storing the object using the `min` function of `lodash`

Comment: You can't. `arr[1]` and `sub` are both references to the same object, but `sub` is not pointer to the array itself.

Comment: Please note that there is a big difference between `sub.c = "x"` and `sub = null`. In the first case you are *reading* the value of `sub` and mutate the object, in the second you are *writing* a new value to `sub`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete element from array, be it primitive value or object, you still use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). To find element index you would use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). It possible because:

> indexOf compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict equality (the same method used by the ===, or triple-equals, operator).

So combined together

```
arr.splice(arr.indexOf(sub), 1);
```

Take a look at this demo:

```js
var arr = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {c: 3, d: 4}]
var sub = arr[1];

alert('Before: ' + JSON.stringify(arr));

arr.splice(arr.indexOf(sub), 1);

alert('After: ' + JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Answer (score 2):

> So the question is: how do I remove `{c: 3, d: 4}` from the array by using sub

There is no way to do that directly.

Relationships in JavaScript are one-way.

`sub` is a reference to an object. `arr[1]` is a reference to the same object.

There is no direct way to get from the object to `sub` or to `arr[1]`.

Since you know `arr` contains a reference to the object, you can search for a copy of that reference using `indexOf`.

```
var index = arr.indexOf(sub);
```

You can then use it to remove the element from the array.

```
arr.splice(index, 1);
```